# vertically center dynamic content within a floated element

Tags: html, css

I have two floated columns, THEY  HAVE TO BE FLOATED, I can't use `display:table`. I want the `<p>` element to be center aligned vertically without setting a height to it because different translations will be loaded in. The whole container wrapper is determined by the height of the image. Is this possible?

```
.wrapper{
     width:100%;
      max-width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .col{
    float:left;
    width:50%;

    }

    p{

        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }   


    <div class="wrapper">
           <div class="col col-1">
               <img alt="" src="http://images.hugoboss.com/is/image/boss/W14FA_BW_007_sRGB_14-10-23_collection?$marketing_asset$&amp;wid=470&amp;hei=400">
           </div>
           <div class="col col-2">
              <p>Test text</p>
           </div>
        </div>
```

The reason for having floats is because I want to swap the order of them at different breakpoints.

http://jsfiddle.net/xuvb7ytx/

Comment: Try setting padding-top using javascript to half of image height.

Comment: I would highly recommend learning about css positioning. this video here explains it all quite well. This will give you a way to both align vertically and to do away with float. http://youtu.be/aFtByxWjfLY

Comment: can you use any `display` in your `.col`?

Comment: it's just I need to swap the order of them at different breakpoints

Comment: How are you making the column divs the same height? It's not going to happen automatically.

Comment: Try this  only by CSS http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/fb0mb8c2/

Answer (score 0):

this is how it can be done with jquery

```js
var a = parseInt($('#image').css('height')) / 2;
var b = parseInt($('#text').css('height')) / 2;
a = a - b;
$('#text').css('margin-top', a);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="image" class="col col-1">
    <img alt="" src="http://images.hugoboss.com/is/image/boss/W14FA_BW_007_sRGB_14-10-23_collection?$marketing_asset$&amp;wid=470&amp;hei=400">
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2" id="text">
    <p>your text here<br>jhgsydugas]y</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What we are doing is calculating height of `image` and `text` divs and calculating margin for `text` as

margin-top(text) = (height(image)/2) - (height(text)/2)